Aggregate data in array of structs to strings - BigQuery
I have some data that in simplified terms looks something like this:

What I want to do is summarise this into a table where each ID appears once, and the parts are summarise in some form of aggregate string for each column, but importantly that each of these aggregate strings maintains the same order. For example:

For a single column this would be easy enough, but in order to guarantee I maintain the order I presumably need to use an array of structs? In which case I can use some SQL along these lines to aggregate the data:
SELECT id, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(part_id AS ids, part_value AS values)) AS part FROM table
At this stage, however, I'm stuck on how I would aggregate each element of the STRUCT separately and turn it back into a 'normal' field.
Edited for clarity: replaced screenshots, as previous example had unique values in part_id and they were already ordered. Neither of these should have been assumed.

The database system may return the results in any order, you need to use the ORDER BY clause to define the sorting based on one or more columns ( Example you can use a unique ID or a date (timestamp) column, or both ):
SELECT id, STRING_AGG(part_id, '|' ORDER BY ordering_column) as part_ids,
           STRING_AGG(CAST(part_value AS STRING), '|' ORDER BY ordering_column) as part_values
FROM mytable
GROUP  id


Thanks. Unfortunately there is no unique column such as timestamp (in this case timestamp is done at the "ID" level, not the part level. Is there a way of applying a "dummy" unique ID to these values within the function? e.g. ROW_NUMBER()?

Unfortunatly you can't ! without a column to define the order, the results from ROW_NUMBER() could also be non-deterministic

I guess I'll just have to order over all columns and treat that as 'unique' - after all any duplicates that result over all columns won't really matter... Thanks :)

We can use the make-use string aggregator function.
SELECT 
id, 
string_agg(part_ids order by part_ids  ),
string_agg( cast(part_value  as string) order by part_ids),
FROM table
group by id;

